# Is it possible to write soap web services using .net core?

Tags: web-services, soap, .net-core

I have been tasked to explore if its possible to write soap services on .net core. It seems like there is a test version of WCF for consuming. But i have not been able to find much abt producing soap web services. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the WCF client libraries have been [ported to .net core](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf) but the server side libraries haven't as of the time of writing. There is [this long running issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1200) which is a request for the server side libraries to be ported over and Microsoft are saying it will happen, see this from a few weeks ago:

> WCF for .NET Core is very much on our radar, and we are working with the ASP.NET Core to prioritize this work. We will share more details when they are available to broadcast publicly.

Of course you don't need WCF necessarily to do SOAP but I guess that's what you were asking. A quick search gives [this repo](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore) and I guess the are probably others but WCF isn't there yet.

Comment: Microsoft is asking for feedback on this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/whereismysolution/2017/09/08/we-want-your-feedback/

Answer (score -1):

If you need something production quality on .NET Core now you can use Service Stack. Info on SOAP services is here:

http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support

Info on .NET Core is here:
http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore

Unfortunately it is not a free product, but it's pretty solid and in my view worth the cost.
https://servicestack.net/pricing

Comment: *Info on .NET Core is here: http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore* Did you read this?? *Whilst we were able to make most of ServiceStack’s features available in .NET Core there are a number of features that we’re not able to support, these include: ... SOAP Support*